# Error "(.text+0x17f): reubicación truncada para ajustar:" aunque el tamaño es correcto

Tags: c, variables-globales

Estoy haciendo un programa que multiplica un vector v1 por una matriz M dando como resultado un vector v2. Tanto los vectores como la matriz son globales y han de serlo. Tengo una macro MAX definida para inicializar los vectores y a partir de ahí el usuario ingresa el espacio a usar N (si N > MAX entonces N = MAX). Mi problema es que al compilar me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y sé que esto pasa cuando el tamaño con el que inicializado todo es demasiado grande pero no es el caso, ¿a qué se puede deber? Adjunto el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#else
#define omp_get_thread_num() 0
#endif

#define MAX 33554432
int v1[MAX], v2[MAX], M[MAX][MAX];


int main(int argc, char **argv)  {
srand(time(NULL));
struct timespec t_ini, t_fin;
double tiempo; 
int suma = 0, num;
if (argc!=2)
{
    printf("Argumentos incorrectos\n");
    exit(-1);
}

unsigned int N = atoi(argv[1]);
if (N>MAX) N=MAX;


//RELLENAMOS EL VECTOR
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
   //num = rand () % 11;
   v1[i] = i;
}

//RELLENAMOS LA MATRIZ
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
   {
      // num = rand () % 11;
       M[i][j] = j;
   }

}

clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&t_ini);

//OPERACIONES
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
   suma = 0;
   for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
   {
      suma += (M[i][j] * v1[j]);
   }
   v2[i] = suma;

}

clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&t_fin);
tiempo = (double) (t_fin.tv_sec-t_ini.tv_sec) + (double) ((t_fin.tv_nsec - 
t_ini.tv_nsec)/(1.e+9));

printf("Tiempo: %11.9f\n", tiempo);
if (N<=15)
{
    printf("El vector resultado es: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",v2[i]);   
    }
    printf("\n");
}

printf("El primer elemento es %d y el último es %d",v2[0], v2[N-1]);



printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Tu variable `M` tiene un tamaño de `33554432 * 33554432 = 1,125899907x10¹⁵`. Igual eso influye.

Comment: Influía muchísimo, muchas gracias!